# Cant find the common jar on kotlin multi-platform project

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform

I created by own multi-platform project and i have implementations for `jvm` and `ios`. Once I build the project it generated 5 jars

- Name-jvm.jar
- Name-jvm-sources.jar
- Name-ios-sources.jar
- Name-metadata.jar
- Name-metadata-sources.jar

Where `Name` is the name of my project. But am not able to get `Name-common.jar`. So when I publish the same to bintray, I cant find `Name-common.jar` through pom.xml is present. 
I there anything wrong with my understanding of the multi-platform builds

Comment: default publications in KMP are called `metadata` and not `common`. So you are supposed to look for `Name-metadata.jar` which you already pointed out that you already have

Comment: Awesome !! thanks. I figured that out in some time. Can you help me with one more doubt, how can I combine all the ios jars (different) platforms into one native jar.

Comment: IOS only has sources jar, because its binary is published in klib format. And to be honest, I haven't dealt with kotlin native that much. So, I can't advice you more about having some sort of ios fat jar

Comment: Thanks ! This is awesome, if you can put this as answer I will accept it !

Comment: @andylamax, Any help with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61920418/kotlin-multi-platform-framework-file-is-too-large :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default artifacts names in kotlin multiplatform publications modules are as follows.

if your project is called `name`, it will have following publications for each target

---

1. Common -> `name-metadata.jar`
2. JVM    -> `name-jvm.jar`
3. JS     -> `name-js.jar` (with name.js inside)
4. Android-> `name-android.jar` (for release build type) or/and `name-android-debug.jar` (for debug)

I am not a kotlin/native user but i believe ios would have something like this

5. ios    -> `name-ios.klib`
   e.t.c

So referring to your issue, you can access your module as just `name-metadata.jar`, or with gradle, `com.group.name:name-metadata:${version}`

If you are going to use it in another multiplatform project, you can just type the name of the project (i.e. `com.group.name:name:${version}`) all along. Gradle metadata will resolve it to respective targets