# Kotlin multi-platform framework file is too large

Tags: ios, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

We created a multi-platform framework file by building my project with the following `packForXCode`. It creates a framework file of the size `5.3 MB`, which is too large. When I add it as part of my iOS extension module, it fails during initiation. The file works fine when inited in the main app.

My pack for Xcode:

```
task packForXcode(type: Sync) {
    final File frameworkDir = new File(buildDir, "xcode-frameworks")
    final String mode = project.findProperty("XCODE_CONFIGURATION")?.toUpperCase() ?: 'DEBUG'
    final def framework = kotlin.targets.iosArm64.binaries.getFramework(mode)

    inputs.property "mode", mode
    dependsOn framework.linkTask

    from { framework.outputFile.parentFile }
    into frameworkDir

    doLast {
        new File(frameworkDir, 'gradlew').with {
            text = "#!/bin/bash\nexport 'JAVA_HOME=${System.getProperty("java.home")}'\ncd '${rootProject.rootDir}'\n./gradlew \$@\n"
            setExecutable(true)
        }
    }
}
```

Adding the source set details:

```
sourceSets {
        commonMain {
            dependencies {
                implementation kotlin("stdlib-common")
            }
        }
        iosMain.dependencies {

        }
}
```

Also there are not other dependencies
Can I make `stdlib-common` compileOnly ? How can I reduce the framework size. Am I blocked ?

Edit: At the same time the ios.jar is just 20kb

Adding error logs:

```
#0  0x0000000198726538 in _platform_memmove ()
#1  0x0000000104bcd514 in kfun:kotlin.collections.copyInto@kotlin.LongArray.(kotlin.LongArray;kotlin.Int;kotlin.Int;kotlin.Int)kotlin.LongArray ()
#2  0x0000000104bcd348 in kfun:kotlin.collections.copyOfUninitializedElements$stdlib@kotlin.LongArray.(kotlin.Int;kotlin.Int)kotlin.LongArray ()
#3  0x0000000104bcd114 in kfun:kotlin.collections.copyOfUninitializedElements$stdlib@kotlin.LongArray.(kotlin.Int)kotlin.LongArray ()
#4  0x0000000104bcd004 in kfun:kotlin.collections.copyOf@kotlin.LongArray.(kotlin.Int)kotlin.LongArray ()
#5  0x0000000104bf3928 in kfun:kotlin.native.BitSet.ensureCapacity#internal ()
#6  0x0000000104bf3f3c in kfun:kotlin.native.BitSet.set(kotlin.ranges.IntRange;kotlin.Boolean) ()
#7  0x0000000104bf3c70 in kfun:kotlin.native.BitSet.set(kotlin.Int;kotlin.Int;kotlin.Boolean) ()
#8  0x0000000104c42f30 in kfun:kotlin.text.regex.CharClass.add(kotlin.Int;kotlin.Int)kotlin.text.regex.CharClass ()
#9  0x0000000104c633b0 in kfun:kotlin.text.regex.Pattern.processRangeExpression#internal ()
#10 0x0000000104c62904 in kfun:kotlin.text.regex.Pattern.processRangeExpression#internal ()
#11 0x0000000104c61fe4 in kfun:kotlin.text.regex.Pattern.processRange#internal ()
#12 0x0000000104c601dc in kfun:kotlin.text.regex.Pattern.processTerminal#internal ()
#13 0x0000000104c5c698 in kfun:kotlin.text.regex.Pattern.processSubExpression#internal ()
#14 0x0000000104c58c58 in kfun:kotlin.text.regex.Pattern.processExpression#internal ()
#15 0x0000000104c5fe18 in kfun:kotlin.text.regex.Pattern.processTerminal#internal ()
#16 0x0000000104c5c698 in kfun:kotlin.text.regex.Pattern.processSubExpression#internal ()
#17 0x0000000104c5c080 in kfun:kotlin.text.regex.Pattern.processSubExpression#internal ()
#18 0x0000000104c58c58 in kfun:kotlin.text.regex.Pattern.processExpression#internal ()
#19 0x0000000104c5fe18 in kfun:kotlin.text.regex.Pattern.processTerminal#internal ()
#20 0x0000000104c5c698 in kfun:kotlin.text.regex.Pattern.processSubExpression#internal ()
#21 0x0000000104c58c58 in kfun:kotlin.text.regex.Pattern.processExpression#internal ()
#22 0x0000000104c5fe18 in kfun:kotlin.text.regex.Pattern.processTerminal#internal ()
#23 0x0000000104c5c698 in kfun:kotlin.text.regex.Pattern.processSubExpression#internal ()
#24 0x0000000104c58c58 in kfun:kotlin.text.regex.Pattern.processExpression#internal ()
#25 0x0000000104c5fe18 in kfun:kotlin.text.regex.Pattern.processTerminal#internal ()
#26 0x0000000104c5c698 in kfun:kotlin.text.regex.Pattern.processSubExpression#internal ()
#27 0x0000000104c5c080 in kfun:kotlin.text.regex.Pattern.processSubExpression#internal ()
#28 0x0000000104c58c58 in kfun:kotlin.text.regex.Pattern.processExpression#internal ()
#29 0x0000000104c5fe18 in kfun:kotlin.text.regex.Pattern.processTerminal#internal ()
#30 0x0000000104c5c698 in kfun:kotlin.text.regex.Pattern.processSubExpression#internal ()
#31 0x0000000104c58c58 in kfun:kotlin.text.regex.Pattern.processExpression#internal ()
#32 0x0000000104c5fe18 in kfun:kotlin.text.regex.Pattern.processTerminal#internal ()
#33 0x0000000104c5c698 in kfun:kotlin.text.regex.Pattern.processSubExpression#internal ()
#34 0x0000000104c58c58 in kfun:kotlin.text.regex.Pattern.processExpression#internal ()
#35 0x0000000104c57418 in kfun:kotlin.text.regex.Pattern.<init>(kotlin.String;kotlin.Int)kotlin.text.regex.Pattern ()
#36 0x0000000104c57794 in kfun:kotlin.text.regex.Pattern.<init>(kotlin.String;kotlin.Int;kotlin.Int;kotlin.native.internal.DefaultConstructorMarker?)kotlin.text.regex.Pattern ()
#37 0x0000000104c10984 in kfun:kotlin.text.Regex.<init>(kotlin.String)kotlin.text.Regex ()
#38 0x0000000104cbae0c in ___lldb_unnamed_symbol189$$MyMessageFilterExtension ()
#39 0x0000000104ce9200 in (anonymous namespace)::initRuntime() ()
#40 0x0000000104ce901c in Kotlin_initRuntimeIfNeeded ()
#41 0x0000000104cc8a84 in +[KotlinBase allocWithZone:] ()
#42 0x0000000104ba5ee4 in My_categorizerSmsClassifierBuilder.__allocating_init() ()
#43 0x0000000104ba5db4 in SMSCategorizerBuilder.build(completion:) ()
#44 0x0000000104ba5160 in MessageFilterExtension.filterByContent(for:completion:) at /Users/vs/Development/my-iphone/My_iOS/MyMessageFilterExtension/MessageFilterExtension.swift:75
#45 0x0000000104ba4a54 in MessageFilterExtension.handle(_:context:completion:) at /Users/vs/Development/my-iphone/My_iOS/MyMessageFilterExtension/MessageFilterExtension.swift:56
#46 0x0000000104ba528c in @objc MessageFilterExtension.handle(_:context:completion:) ()
#47 0x00000001b8fefef0 in -[ILMessageFilterExtensionContext handleQueryRequest:reply:] ()
#48 0x0000000198f283d4 in __NSXPCCONNECTION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_EXPORTED_OBJECT_S2__ ()
#49 0x0000000198d31e40 in -[NSXPCConnection _decodeAndInvokeMessageWithEvent:flags:] ()
#50 0x0000000198f284f8 in message_handler ()
#51 0x000000019861aae0 in _xpc_connection_call_event_handler ()
#52 0x000000019861ae68 in _xpc_connection_mach_event ()
#53 0x00000001986c4408 in _dispatch_client_callout4 ()
#54 0x00000001986db2f0 in _dispatch_mach_msg_invoke ()
#55 0x00000001986ca72c in _dispatch_lane_serial_drain ()
#56 0x00000001986dbf2c in _dispatch_mach_invoke ()
#57 0x00000001986ca72c in _dispatch_lane_serial_drain ()
#58 0x00000001986cb2c4 in _dispatch_lane_invoke ()
#59 0x00000001986d4928 in _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread ()
#60 0x000000019872b714 in _pthread_wqthread ()
```

Comment: What's the failure message? How are you defining "too large"?

Comment: @KevinGalligan added the error log. When run the same in normal app it works fine, but if I init it in sms extension it fails

Comment: All cross-platform frameworks have an overhead of at least several MB, I don't think there is much you can do about it (besides not using a cross-platform framework).

Comment: I just want to know whether its expected, I mean the size, just to make sure that am not doing anything wrong. Also is there any way to reduce the same. Also, @Dalmas, are you sure about your answer, have you tried creating any such framework file ?

Comment: We're currently spending a lot of time measuring KMP size overhead. It really depends what you're doing. If you're creating one small function, the overhead is about 150k, but goes up pretty fast if you've got a lot of libraries and code.

Comment: I'm not sure your issue is the framework size. Framework sizes on disk have little relevance to what they are when uploaded to the app store. I would try some other things first. Also, if you have no libraries, how much code do you have? If it's just a few classes and functions, and you build a static framework, I'd expect overhead of 250k-500k compressed size. Maybe a meg uncompressed (maybe).